# Rails, attribute confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I don't like how Rails confirmation validations attach the message "doesn't match confirmation" to the parent attribute...

```
validates(:password, {confirmation: true})
```

It makes more sense from a UX standpoint that an error should be passed to the confirmation, "does not match password", when the two don't match.

Adding any validations to a confirmation attribute seem to be ignored...

```
validates(:password_confirmation, {my_validation: true, length: {maximum: 3}})
```

**`length` validation is just for testing purposes. Note that there's no error on the Password Confirmation field in this screenshot:

[image: form screenshot]

I created a custom validation, `better_validation`:

```
class BetterConfirmationValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    parent_attr = attr_name.to_s
    parent_attr['_confirmation'] = ''
    unless value == record.send(parent_attr)
      record.errors.add(attr_name, :better_confirmation, options.merge(:value => value))
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work unless I name the confirmation field something different (i.e. add an 's' on the end...`:password_confirmations`).

Is there a way to tell Rails not to take over and let me apply validations to `foo_confirmation` attributes?

Thanks!

### Edit

Model code...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :name,
    presence: true,
    length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    format: { with: /\A.+@[a-z\d\-.]+\z/i },
    uniqueness: true
  validates :password,
    length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 255 },
    presence: { on: :create }
  validates :password_confirmation,
    presence: true,
    better_confirmation: true
.
.
.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with:

```
validates :password,
  presence: true,
  length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 255 },
  confirmation: true
```

or with this:

```
validate :password_confirmation_match


def password_confirmation_match
  self.errors[:password_confirmation] << "does not match password" if self.password_confirmation.to_s != self.password
end
```